# Reverse a default flag

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link, pwd

As a context. I have a folder which I have symlinked into my `$HOME` directory.

```
~> ls -s /var/www/to_link "$HOME/linked"
```

I `cd` into `"$HOME/linked"`

So, by default, `pwd` shows the current directory including symlinks. In this case, it would be `/home/christopher/linked`. If I want to have it return `/var/www/to_link` I have to type `pwd -P`. I generally find this second form more useful than the first, but I would like both to be available.

- Is it possible to have `pwd` default to include the `-P` flag, and then use another flag to include symlinks? So basically, `pwd` would return `/var/www/to_link` and `pwd -X` (or some other flag) would return the original `/home/christopher/linked`.

Answer (score 1):

Both `cd` and `pwd` have options `-P` and `-L`. It seems you want to use `cd -P` by default (which then sets $PWD to the physical directory, which then affects your bash prompt and the output of `pwd`).

You can put one of these in your .bashrc:

```
alias cd='cd -P'

cd () { builtin cd -P "$@"; }
```

If you want to see "~/linked" in your bash prompt, you'll use the "logical" cd: `cd -L ~/linked`